# printing warnings by R

Tags: r, warnings

I have a code on a file that works on a matrix and I read it by using

> source("filecode.r")

As the matrix that the code works with must have some specific characteristics, I would like to print a message to remember the user that the input matrix must be formatted with those characteristics.

The code is this:

```
n<- nrow(aa)
d_ply(aa, 1, function(row){
cu<- dist(as.numeric(row[-1]))
cucu<- as.matrix(cu)
saveRDS(cucu, file = paste0(row$ID, ".rds"))
}, .progress='text', .print = TRUE)
```

Ideally I would like to add a warning message appearing before the code starts running...like this:

```
Warning(“1) did you write ‘ID’ in position [1,1] of the input matrix?;  
2) is your matrix saved as a .txt? 
3) ensure that the matrix file does not have empty rows at the end”)
```

and receiving also a question like "do you want to go on then?".
Thank you in advance for all suggestions!
Gab

Comment: Isn't it possible to just check that in your script and just print the warning when it's not in the right format?
I'd find it annoying when I have to explicitly tell the script that I want to execute it _every time_ I run it. Makes running it from another script in non-interactive mode also harder.

Comment: yes, you're right...if you are the ONLY user of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put that at the beginning of your file:

```
check <- readline(prompt="Warning!\n(1) did you write 'ID' in position [1,1] of the input matrix? \n(2) is your matrix saved as a .txt?\n(3) ensure that the matrix file does not have empty rows at the end\n\n Do you wish to continue? (y/n)")
if(check == "n") stop("Aborted.")
print(check)  #Here would follow your code instead
```

If you type "y" the following code will be evaluated. If you type "n", the script stops and prints the message inside `stop()`.

[image]

---

You could also make sure that only 'y' and 'n' are accepted by putting the prompt statement inside of a while loop:

```
check <- NA
while(!(check %in% c('y','n'))) {
  check <- readline(prompt="Warning!\n(1) did you write 'ID' in position [1,1] of the input matrix? \n(2) is your matrix saved as a .txt?\n(3) ensure that the matrix file does not have empty rows at the end\n\n Do you wish to continue? (y/n)")
}
if(check == "n") stop("Aborted.")
```